# Efficient coding for loops with names for variables

Tags: python, performance, loops

I have some formulas that I have defined as functions.

I've then 'named' them using particular parameters as I then need to use the output in further formula's which makes it easier and neater.

I now need to loop the defined function to give the outputs for each month over the year, and when I put in the name of the function into the while loop, it just gives me the one answer 12 times over, but when I put the full function into the loop it works.

Is there a way that I can loop the function by using it's name because as my formulae are progressing, they're getting more and more complex and the code is getting busy and confusing.

```
def growPOP(p, T, r, K):
    #formula to calculate the new population at the end of a month.
    #p = initial population, T = total initial population
    #r = growth rate per time, K = carrying capacity
    GrPp = p + ((p * r)*((K - T) / K))
    return(GrPp)

def rt(a, b, t):
    #formula to calculate growth rate for brown fish
    #a & b are constants given, t = the month number
    rt = a + (b*sin(((2*pi)*t)/12))
    return rt

ca = 0.052
cb = 0.132   
brownPOP = 19000
goldPOP = 4400
totalPOP = brownPOP + goldPOP
carryK = 104800
redcarryK = 0.998
newcarryK = (carryK*redcarryK) + (ep/10) #ep is an input figure - for now it's 0.
month = 1
brownGrowth = growPOP(brownPOP, totalPOP, rt(ca, cb, month), carryK)

while month <= 2:
    print "Month ", month
    print "Grown brown fish: ", growPOP(brownPOP, totalPOP, rt(ca, cb, month), carryK)
    brownPOP = endbrownPOP
    goldPOP = endgoldPOP
    totalPOP = endtotalPOP
    carryK = newcarryK
    month = month + 1
```

So in the above loop it gives me exactly the output I want, but I really want the loop to say "print "Grown brown fish: ", brownGrowth" and still work.

There are other formulae to get brownPOP to endbrownPOP but there's quite a few and they work, so I didn't think they needed to be entered in to complicate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot to recalculate brownGrowth in every loop iteration?

```
brownGrowth = growPOP(brownPOP, totalPOP, rt(ca, cb, month), carryK) 
while month <= 2: 
    print "Month ", month 
    print "Grown brown fish: ", brownGrowth
    brownPOP = endbrownPOP  
    goldPOP = endgoldPOP  
    totalPOP = endtotalPOP  
    carryK = newcarryK  
    month = month + 1
```

Move the `brownGrowth = formula` line to inside while loop:

```
while month <= 2: 
    brownGrowth = growPOP(brownPOP, totalPOP, rt(ca, cb, month), carryK) 
    print "Month ", month 
    print "Grown brown fish: ", brownGrowth
    brownPOP = endbrownPOP 
    goldPOP = endgoldPOP 
    totalPOP = endtotalPOP 
    carryK = newcarryK 
    month = month + 1
```

Comment: sweet! This does it :-)  Thanks @nvuono!

Comment: The line `brownGrowth = brownGrowth` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading you correctly, you want `brownGrowth` to not *store* the result of the function call to `growPop()`, but to *become* that function call. So what you want to do is define a `brownGrowth` *as a function.*

```
brownGrowth = lambda: growPOP(brownPOP, totalPOP, rt(ca, cb, month), carryK)
```

Then in your loop, *call* that function:

```
print "Grown brown fish: ", brownGrowth()
```

However, there is really nothing wrong with the way you have it now, and I don't think it's any clearer the way you want to change it -- in fact, it's hiding what goes into that number behind an argumentless function. Also, there's nothing more efficient about it: it's *less* efficient because there's an extra layer of function call in the recipe.

Comment: Also a great time to introduce `functools.partial`. One of my favorite functions ever.

Comment: Yeah, `functools.partial` is very similar, however I believe it will "fix" the values of the variables at the time the partial is created rather than letting them "float" as a closure does.

Comment: Thanks @kindall - I did think about making 'brownGrowth' a function in it's own right but dis-regarded it because it would complicate it further!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using a lambda:

```
brownGrowth = lambda: growPOP(brownPOP, totalPOP, rt(ca, cb, month), carryK)
```

you could also use [partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from functools:

```
from functools import partial
brownGrowth = partial(growPOP, brownPOP, totalPOP, rt(ca, cb, month), carryK)
```

Then call it like:

```
print "Grown brown fish: ", brownGrowth()
```

But, again, it's entirely unnecessary, just put the function call in the loop, it's less code.